# $L/K$ being formally smooth implies $L/K$ is separable?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

If $L/K$ is a finite separable fields extension, then it is formally smooth, i.e., for every commutative diagram

[image]

where $B$ is a ring and $I\subseteq B$ is an ideal satisying $I^{2}=0$ there exists a lifting $\lambda\colon L\to B$ making the diagram commute.

I need to prove the converse. If $L/K$ is finite and not separable, then it is not formally smooth.
This is how one could proceed. If $K$ has characteristic $p$ and $a\in L$ is not a $p$-th power in $K$ then suppose that $K(\sqrt[p]{a})$ is formally smooth over $K$.

Then
$$K(\sqrt[p]{a})\otimes_{K} K(\sqrt[p]{a})\cong \frac{K(\sqrt[p]{a})[x]}{(x^{p}-a)}\cong\frac{K(\sqrt[p]{a})[x]}{(x-\sqrt[p]{a})^{p}}$$
should be formally smooth because https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00TJ but I want to prove that this is a contradiction because, in reality, $\frac{K(\sqrt[p]{a})[x]}{(x-\sqrt[p]{a})^{p}}$ is not formally smooth. But I am unable to prove this.

To conclude the proof, one could demonstrate that if $L/K$ were formally smooth, then by considering $K_{0}$ such that $K\subseteq K_{0}\subseteq L$ and $L=K_{0}(\sqrt[p^{r_{1}}]{a_{1}},\dots,\sqrt[p^{r_{m}}]{a_{m}})$ we get a formally smooth subextension $K_{0}(\sqrt[p](a_{1}))/K_{0}$, so a contradiction. This is another point that I am unable to prove. Is it true that given $K\subseteq F \subseteq L$, if $L/K$ is formally smooth, then both $L/F$ and $F/K$ are also formally smooth?

Comment: Is $L/K$ assumed to be finite, or algebraic? (Please add the answer to the question.)

Comment: It is assumed finited, I forgot this.

Comment: Hint: If the extension defines a smooth morphism, then it is etale and hence separable. So, it suffices to prove smoothness. But Spec L -> Spec K is finitely presented and formally smooth, hence smooth (see Stacks Project). So you could also look at the proof of   "locally finitely presented formally smooth implies smooth"

Answer (score 1):

You want the following statement: Let $K$ be a characteristic $p$ field. Then $K[x]/x^p$ is not formally smooth over $K$.

Let $B=K[\epsilon]/\epsilon^{p+1}$ and $B/I=K[\epsilon]/\epsilon^{p}$. Let $K\to B$ be the obvious map, and let $K[x]/x^p\to B/I$ send $x$ to $\epsilon$. Then there is no lift $K[x]/x^p\to B=K[\epsilon]/\epsilon^{p+1}$, since $\alpha^p=0$ in $B$ implies $\alpha\in\epsilon^2B$.